# Laravel query relation of relation in load method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, eager-loading

I have 2 models: `Supplier` and `Product` which are connected via `SupplierProduct` table with additional fields

For a given `$supplier` I need to load it's `SupplierProducts` (with attached products) filtered by `where` conditions in both `SupplierProduct` and `Product` models

Loading everything would look like:

```
$supplier->load([
   'supplierProducts.product'
]);
```

Now how can I load with conditions for both `SupplierProduct` and `Product` ?

```
$supplier->load([
    'supplierProducts' => function ($query) use ($supplierProductParam, $productParam) {
        $query->where('field', $supplierProductParam);       
        // can I query supplierProducts.product here?         
     }, // or can I query supplierProducts.product here?
]);
```

Comment: $query->where('field', $supplierProductParam)
            ->whereHas('product', function ($query) use ($productParam) {
                $query->where('product_field', $productParam);
            });

Comment: @KarlHill I think that's it, now I wonder how can I load it as (hasMany) `products` with pivot being `supplier_products` with the same query params?

Comment: why are you creating a relationship for the pivot table? it is handled automatically by a `BelongsToMany` relationship .... if you set it up correctly you can use things like `wherePivot` to filter based on the pivot table

Answer (score 0):

Define them as many to many relations to each other, using belongsToMany using withPivot in the definition. That relation has wherePivot method to conditionate the pivot model.

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withPivot('active', 'created_by')
```

Also you can use where on the relation. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#filtering-queries-via-intermediate-table-columns

```
Suplier::query()->with('products', function (Relation $relation): void {$relation->wherePivot(....);});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add additional filters in the many to many relationship you can use:

```
wherePivot('id', 1)
```

or

```
wherePivotIn('id', [1])
```

Further official info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#filtering-queries-via-intermediate-table-columns)

In your case:

```
$supplier->load([
    'supplierProducts' => function ($query) use ($supplierProductParam, $productParam) {
      $query->where('field',$supplierProductParam)->wherePivotIn('fieldonmanytomany',$supplierProductParam);       
      },
]);
```